Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:Project1/StartScreen.dart'. Try creating the file referenced by the URI, or try using a URI for a file
Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:Project1/StartScreen.dart'.
Try creating the file referenced by the URI, or try using a URI for a file that does exist.darturi_does_not_exist
despite the path is correct ig and also there is a file with exact name as the path it still shows an error

Probably you didnt run the flutter pub get command. Please add your code snippet so that we can verify.

Try these commands(in the root folder of the project, not any subfolders):
flutter packages get 
flutter packages upgrade
and then restart your editor
